# Laravel Sail "build path ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0 either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL."

Tags: laravel, docker-compose, laravel-sail

I'm using Laravel 8.x with Sail using PHP 8.0, recently, I actually messed up my compose.json file resulting in issues with the vendor, trying to recreate the project from scratch, I deleted the vendor folder.

Normally, docker-compose would build and create the `/path/to/project/vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/` directory with its appropriate content, but for some reason, I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR: build path /path/to/project/vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0 either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.
```

I tried using `docker system prune` and deleting the existing containers manually through the Docker Desktop interface, and I even tried running it with `docker-compose build --no-cache`, I still get the same error.

Is there a way to fix this or should I just clone my project again and try to build it?

Note: I'm using an old Mac without the possibility of just manually running `composer install` so any of my interactions with the instance relies on the docker container working.

Comment: > Note: I'm using an old Mac without the possibility of just manually running composer install so any of my interactions with the instance relies on the docker container working.

- Why?

Comment: @onlineThomas The why should be unrelated here, but since you asked, it's an iMac with the latest OS version of 10.12 (no longer supported by Apple or Homebrew) so I haven't really been able to get php 8 working on it.

Answer (score 3):

```
docker run --rm --interactive --tty --volume C:/path/to/project:/app composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-scripts
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The standard procedure for setting up any Laravel project should be running `composer install`, so an inability to do so really ties one's hands here.

However, in this case, where the only way for me to run composer was through docker, I elected to use the [laravel.build](https://laravel.build/example-app) website to create a new project and copy the `vendor` folder over. Here's the script:

```sh
docker info > /dev/null 2>&1

# Ensure that Docker is running...
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Docker is not running."

    exit 1
fi

docker run --rm \
    -v $(pwd):/opt \
    -w /opt \
    laravelsail/php80-composer:latest \
    bash -c "laravel new example-app && cd example-app && php ./artisan sail:install --with=mysql,redis,meilisearch,mailhog,selenium"

cd example-app

CYAN='\033[0;36m'
LIGHT_CYAN='\033[1;36m'
WHITE='\033[1;37m'
NC='\033[0m'

echo ""

if sudo -n true 2>/dev/null; then
    sudo chown -R $USER: .
    echo -e "${WHITE}Get started with:${NC} cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up"
else
    echo -e "${WHITE}Please provide your password so we can make some final adjustments to your application's permissions.${NC}"
    echo ""
    sudo chown -R $USER: .
    echo ""
    echo -e "${WHITE}Thank you! We hope you build something incredible. Dive in with:${NC} cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up"
fi
```

After that, running `./vendor/bin/sail up -d && ./vendor/bin/sail composer install` fixed the problem.

Comment: This is in no way the best possible answer, but I figured this problem is rather uncommon and may not receive any answers anyway. I will put off picking the best answer for now, hoping for a better solution.